# How to convert a byte array to a integer?

Tags: c, arrays, integer, byte, typeconverter

Lets say I have this byte

```
uint8_t k[8]= {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0};
```

Is there a way to get this to become a single integer or hex?

Comment: I mistakenly flagged this as a duplicate. Please ignore the close vote. My apologies. :-( (It's a poorly written question, because you've failed to show any effort to do this yourself, but it's not a duplicate.)

Comment: Well, you can use a cast for example, but you shouldn't. (Something like  int i=*(int*)k;  )

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry about that, I'll learn more as I go as all these are totally new to me.

Comment: using a cast on array will result in horrible, unwanted results. It will convert the ADDRESS of the array into integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `k` represents 8 bytes of the 64-bit integer, go through the array of 8-bit integers, and shift them into the result left-to-right:

```
uint64_t res = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i != 8 ; i++) {
    res <<= 8;
    res |= k[i];
}
```

The direction of the loop depends on the order in which the bytes of the original `int` are stored in the `k` array. The above snippet shows the MSB-to-LSB order; if the array is LSB-to-MSB, start the loop at 7, and go down to zero.

If the bytes represent individual bits, shift by one rather than eight.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
int convertToInt(uint8_t k[8], bool leastSignificantFirst) { 
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) { 
        if (leastSignificantFirst) { 
            res |= (k[i] & 1) << (7 - i);
        } else {
            res |= (k[i] & 1) << i;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```